# PHP divide el contenido del área de texto e insertar en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Formato: PRECIO|CCN|MONTH|YEAR|CVV|NAME|ADDRESS|CITY|STATE|ZIP|COUNTRY

Example: 12.50|4111222233334444|01|16|123|JOHN DOE|FAKE STREET 123|CHICAGO|ILLINOIS|12345|UNITED STATES OF AMERICA

Este es el código:

```
<textarea id="upload-data" class="textarea" placeholder="Pega el formato correcto.."></textarea>
```

Quiero que al pegar el formato y subir separe cada | e inserte en mysql en cada columna correspondiente.

Comment: Qué probaste? Qué estás usando para conectarte a la base de datos? Desde PHP podes usar [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php).

Comment: todo va  bien al conectar a la base de datos y todo pero no encuentro por ningún lado un ejemplo como ese para poder realizarlo.

Comment: si tienes conocimientos de php puedo mostrarte mi codigo para que lo veas

Comment: Publicá el código donde te conectas a la base de datos y guardás la información.

Comment: dime donde puedo contactarte y te doy acceso para que lo veas todo con claridad.  azeós.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que la fuente de datos sea fiable y no necesitas realizar una consulta parametrizada, te propongo el siguiente código:

```
<form method="post">
<textarea name="datos" id="upload-data" class="textarea" placeholder="Pega el formato correcto.."></textarea>
<button>Enviar</button>
</form>
<?php
// datos de prueba
$formato = 'PRECIO|CCN|MONTH|YEAR|CVV|NAME|ADDRESS|CITY|STATE|ZIP|COUNTRY';
if(isset($_POST['datos'])) $ejemplo=$_POST['datos'];
else $ejemplo = '12.50|4111222233334444|01|16|123|JOHN DOE|FAKE STREET 123|CHICAGO|ILLINOIS|12345|UNITED STATES OF AMERICA';
// separo los datos
$campos = explode('|',$formato);
$datos  = explode('|',$ejemplo);
// formo los querys SQL
$query_campos = null;
$query_datos  = null;
foreach($campos as $i=>$campo){
    if(!isset($datos[$i])) $datos[$i]=null;
    $query_campos .= $campo.' VARCHAR(63),';
    $query_datos  .= "'".$datos[$i]."',";
}
// me conecto al servidor de bases de datos
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');
// creo la tabla
$conn->query(str_replace(',)',')',"
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS julian(".$query_campos.");
    "));
// inserto el dato recibido
$conn->query(str_replace(',)',')',"
        INSERT INTO julian VALUES (".$query_datos.");
    "));
// muestro el contenido de la tabla
echo '<pre>';
print_r($conn->query("
        SELECT * FROM julian;
    ")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Con la función `explode()` separas campos y datos y, con la clase `mysqli`, creas la tabla y realizas las inserciones de datos. Finalmente, con un `SELECT`, muestras los datos que has ido almacenando.

Espero que te resulte útil.

Comment: tu ejemplo esta bien amigo, pero los datos son puesto por el usuario en la etiqueta <textarea>. Si quieres ayudarme dime donde te puedo contactar para darte acceso al código del proyecto.

Comment: Hola Julián, en [SO] utilizamos las dudas para que ayuden a más usuarios con problemas similares, no resolvemos problemas concretos sino [Ejemplos mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). En cualquier caso, si quieres contactar conmigo, en mi perfil tienes mi enlace a LinkedIn. Te amplío la respuesta para indicarte cómo obtener los datos del testarea

Comment: Gracias amigo, es que es muy importante para mi, ya te mando un mensaje.